# Unexpected token error on click

Tags: html, onclick, syntax-error

When I set onclick for button in html views:

```
<input type ="button" value="Install" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("deploy", "DeployController")'" />
```

Get error:Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token. What's problem??

Answer (score 0):

you need to use method name only in `onclick="methodName(parameters)"`  and in this method, you can write the logic to redirect the user or any other manipulation.

[reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onclick)

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to this , it may work:

```
 <input type ="button" value="Install" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action(`deploy`,`DeployController`)'">
```

Comment: Why you are not using in a `<script></script>` ?

Comment: `\ ` is used to escape special chars in js. A doublequote in html has to be escaped using `&quot;`